# How can I create an incremental backup system in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: server, 20.04, backup

Once created and make an Ubuntu web server, I would need to create a script which syncs one specific directory with /var/www and move the content which was previously in /var/www to a backup folder with incremental updates. I thought about having a bck folder somewhere in the server and creating automatically folders in it with incremental names once the script is run. How can I create a script which creates a folder named bck/backup1 for the first run, bck/backup2 for the second, etc?

Comment: Existing tools you can use include `rdiff-backup` and `rsnapshot`.  There are plenty of rsync guides if you really want to write your own script.  E.g. http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/

Comment: Some rdiff examples, you can use to start your own version: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2471454&p=14078689#post14078689 & https://rdiff-backup.net/ & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2447368  I only have desktop & use rsync to different flash drives & external SSD. And most critical files to DVD.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, we do not write scripts on demand here. You will need to do your homework and take some time (half a day) to learn a little about bash and how to script. However, if you are very lucky, still someone will present you a tailor made script.

Note that most of what you want can be covered by a single command, `rsync`. `rsync` can make copies, and on subsequent copies, it will only transfer changed and new files, and, with the `--delete` option, delete files in the destination that are not anymore there in the source.

If both file systems of source and destination support all linux file properties and permissions, the following command will make a "mirror copy" of the original. The destination will contain all files from the source, with identical time stamps and ownerships:

```
rsync -av <source> <destination>
```

where, obviously, `<source>` and `<destination>` are path names of the source and destination directory, respectively.

Look at `man rsync`. It has a `--backup-dir` option that allows to make a backup dir containing previous versions of the files in the destination (and then only of the files that have changed).

Another approach is to maintain full backup copies, e.g. like you propose, `bck/backup1`, `bck/backup2` etc using the `--link-dest` option. That way, rsync will link files on the destination that have *not* changed to the same file in a bakcup copy. This way, you have multiple copies of the entire directory structure, however, files that did not change take only once the space. Then, you would move out the contents of `/var/www` to your `bck/backup1` and recreate the contents of `/var/www` based on your "specific directory" in a command line

```
rsync -av --delete --link-dest=bck/backup1 <your_specific_directory>/ /var/www
```

This requires that both `/var/www` and the backups are on the same volume - hardlinks cannot cross volumes.

If the backup needs to be on a different volume, then you will need to 1) create backups of `/var/www` on the different volume (where files from the different versions can be hard-linked) and then 2) update `/var/www` with your "specific directory" (where also --link-dest can be used if source and target are on the same volume).

Comment: I did manage to use rsync some time ago, and in this case I also think it would be the best approach, but it is the automatic renaming what is driving me crazy. I also know about scripting to make this script work, but I don´t know which command would create backup1, backup2... backup100 automatically and mantaining the old backups once it runs (deleting the old ones is a job I can perform manually). It is just this thing what I want to know. Thanks.

Comment: Your question may not have been sufficiently specific. The script should determine the name, prior to invoking rsync: reading the directory, determining the highest number and create a file name with a higher number to pass to the rsync job. I work with a time stamp instead of a number, which is easy and always unique. e.g. for me `mv "$2" "$2-versions/$DATE"` is what renames the previous version of the backup after a new was created. I retrieve the date stamp from the creation date of that backup as: `DATE="$(stat "$2" -c %w | cut -d"." -f1 | tr " " "T")"`